# create custom event log inserting text file information

Tags: batch-file, scripting, event-viewer

I'm currently writing a automated log by batch scripting and supposed to insert into a custom event using eventcreate.

log.txt ( inside contain information on the incidents )

eventcreate /id 101 /l application /t warning /so Something bad happened /d "%log%"

in this case, how am I able to create the event with the content in the log.txt ?

thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If log.txt has a single line for each error you could try something like this in your bat file:

```
for /f "delims=" %%l in (log.txt) do eventcreate /id 101 /l application /t warning /so "Something bad happened" /d "%%l"
```

Otherwise if log.txt might contain multiple lines but you need to create only one event:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

set eventtext=
for /f "delims=" %%l in ( test.txt) do set eventtext=!eventtext! %%l
eventcreate /id 101 /l application /t warning /so "Something bad happened" /d "%eventtext%"
```